# Why does this JQuery dropdown plugin only work on the first dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am using the following JQuery plugin for dropdown menus:

https://code.google.com/p/select-box/

I have 4 dropdown menus but the script only works for the first one.  NOt sure what I need to tweak for it to work on the other 3.

Code:

```
<select name="question1" id="question_1">
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<select name="question2" id="question_2">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<select name="question3" id="question_3">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<select name="question4" id="question_4">
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#question_1").selectbox();
    $("#question_2").selectbox();
    $("#question_3").selectbox();
    $("#question_4").selectbox();
});
</script>
```

Comment: working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/hJvnR/

Comment: Not working.Only first one getting that -->http://jsfiddle.net/VFtk7/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's happening because the plugin uses the deprecated (and now removed) `.live()` event binder.

In `jquery.selectbox-0.2.js` change line 303 from:

```
$("html").live('mousedown', function(e) {
```

to:

```
$("html").on('mousedown', function(e) {
```

Here it is working (without styles) with jQuery 1.10.1: http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Wg/

Comment: Did you replace all `live()` methods in the fiddle?

Comment: @HashemQolami - there's only one and, yes, I replaced it.

Comment: +1 nice job. Consider sending a pull request to the main repository :)

Comment: @HashemQolami - thanks Hashem, I've just suggested the patch :)